# When I specify one field the Subtotal function works, but no subtotal when more than one field is specified. How can I fix this

Tags: excel, vba

When I specify just one field (the 12th field in this example) the subtotal works, however, when I specify more than one field the subtotal does not work and results are displayed without aggregation. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Have gone through MSFT VBA docs..did not help:

works:

```
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, totallist:="12", Replace:=True, pagebreaks:=False, summarybelowdata:=False
```

fails:

```
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, totallist:="8,12", Replace:=True, pagebreaks:=False, summarybelowdata:=False
```

Comment: `totallist:= Array(8,12)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - worth an answer, or closeable as a typo?

Comment: @BigBen stop throwing my words back at me. :)

Answer (score 2):

When doing more than one, one must use an array:

```
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, totallist:= Array(8,12), Replace:=True, pagebreaks:=False, summarybelowdata:=False
```

Comment: Which is *definitely* shown in the code snippet in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.subtotal) haha.

Comment: I am actually using iColList declared as a variant :

         For i = 7 To iFieldCount - 1

             iColList = iColList + CStr(i + 1) + ","

             Next i

        iColList = Left(iColList, Len(iColList) - 1) 

  Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, totallist:=Split(iColList, ","), Replace:=True, _
         pagebreaks:=False, summarybelowdata:=False

Comment: @brand_new_developer that loop does not create an array, it creates a string.  It must be an array.

Comment: Thanks...will check

Comment: @brand_new_developer what version of Excel do you have? if you have Office 365 Excel then `Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, totallist:= Application.WorksheetFunction.Sequence(1, iFieldCount - 8, 7), Replace:=True, pagebreaks:=False, summarybelowdata:=False`